# Angularjs app.js $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have been looking through multiple tutorials and other stack overflow posts with no success for my app.js $routeProvider. Here is github link to project       https://github.com/StudentJoeyJMStudios/PetPinterest.git

Here is my code for app.js

```
  var app = angular.module('se165PetPinterestWebApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngRoute'
  ]);

  app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/select',
            {
                templateUrl: '/views/categorySelection.html',
                controller: 'CatSelCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise(
            {
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
  }]);
```

When I want to navigate to new page I know to injuect $location and manipulate the path using the $location dependency but it does not navigate to new page. Navigating pages this way does it reload js files such as my service file?  Please help thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to include the ng-view directive in your index.html?

> ngView is a directive that complements the $route service by including the rendered template of the current route into the main layout (index.html) file. Every time the current route changes, the included view changes with it according to the configuration of the $route service.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: DO i put that into my index.html only or every html file?

Comment: Yep, ng-view goes in the index.html; it defines where to place the template/view defined in your routing.

Comment: So only in my index.html and no other .html file that I would need to route to?

Comment: It can be placed in any .html file that is not a template .html file loaded by the route.

Comment: I was able to get the routing to somewhat work, it loads the contents of the routed view but still keeps the previous .html contents on the page.